# Alternatives/how to use window.btoa on javascript file on computer

Tags: javascript

I couldn't think of a great title for this, so I'll clear up what I'm asking.

To start off, I don't want to use node. I'm on unix and I'm trying some kind of RSA public/private key encryption, and I'm not able to display the encrypted text without window.btoa().

However, the window object isn't available on a .js file on my computer, being run through terminal with jsc rather than on a website. It must be run through terminal, as this is how I'm going to be running this script in a C++ program I'm writing.

So, are there any alternative libraries or any ways to use window.btoa() on a script being run through my terminal?

Comment: How is btoa related to RSA?

Comment: I need it to decode the values returned by the libraries I'm using.

Example;
`var testv2 = encryptedString(test, "encrypted string", RSAAPP.PKCS1Padding, RSAAPP.RawEncoding);

console.log(window.btoa(testv2));
`

test being an RSAKeyPair object

Comment: There are some hand-written functions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246801/how-can-you-encode-a-string-to-base64-in-javascript/247261). | This is unrelated to RSA.

Comment: @user202729 I'll remove the tag.